# How to add case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sample Table:

```
Table1 (Userid, Name, Salary, Rank)
```

Query:

```
create procedure Proc_SelectDetails
as
@Salary int
begin
     select * from Table1 where salary >= @Salary  
end
```

If `@salary > 50000`, check rank also (with salary) that should be greater than 6 else don't consider rank for comparison.
just compare salary.
How to add this in where clause with help of case statement.

Comment: Please add data set and explain better your logic. So you can write where case salary... then .... end

Comment: In general it's much better to use AND/OR constructions in the WHERE clause, instead of case expressions.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
WHERE Salary >= @Salary
AND (@Salary <= 50000 OR Rank > 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might missed the logic of the where case, anyways this query shows an example of `case when` in `where` if `salary` is grater than `@Salary` compares `rank` with salary.

```
select * from Table1 where 
     case when salary >= @Salary 
        then case when rank >= 6 then 1 
        else 0 end
     else 0 end = 1
```